# Custom wp-query in wordpress rest api

Tags: posts, wp-query, rest-api

For example I have a query with tax and metas and other stuff..

how I can pass it to the rest api so i can call all the data with one call

for example this function

```
function load_special_args() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => '9995',
            ),
        ),
    );
    return $args;
}
```

imaging call:
/wp/v2/posts?args=load_special_args&term=9995

Because I want a special use i dont want to use the 
/wp/v2/posts?categories=id

Answer (score 1):

You can create a route for Rest API using the below code. Simply put this code in your function.php file

```
/* Route For api */
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('wp/v2', 'test', array(
        'methods' => array('GET', 'POST'),
        'callback' => 'test',
    ));
} );
```

And then simply create a callback function **test** and put your stuff in to that function

```
function test(){
  // put your stuff here
}
```

Comment: yes but how i will know that the output of my function will the wp rest api output of post? with all the default data?

Comment: You can use **Postman** tool for check output of your query. Set *Your-site-path/wp-json/wp/v2/test*  
 and by set *POST/GET* method.